# Two git repos on the same machine

Tags: git

I am planning to potray my coding skills and for that i have pushed some of my code into a remote repo at BitBucket. The problem i am facing is that that i have my code in different workspace for example eclipse java ,dr-java java, drupal and salesforce. 
The way i am doing it now is to

```
 git init
```

in each of these folders and pushing my changes to the remote repo. My question is:

Is this the correct way to do things or is there any better ideas for this sort of situation. I ask of a better idea because with this implementation i cannot push my changes without pulling first which means my one piece of code sits in all the four workspaces where three of them are totally unnecessary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clone your bitbucket repo and then copy all the folders which aren't part of that code base?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you have 4 different codes with you, assuming not related to each other.
If this is the case, you should go for 4 different repos rather than pushing all the code in once repo, making the code much bigger and difficult to manage.

You can also try GIT HUB to host your code.